# How to hide or disable view of databases in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

One of my sysadmin tasks is to create databases; every time I create database with Windows Authentication and login from security>new>log-in, and I restrict auto-growth and permissions and etc.

When user log-in from there computer with log-in details (given by me) he can access that particular database and remaining he can see that's it if he want to access it give a error message (like "access restricted").

Up to this is fine. What I want is to hide remaining databases (if we hide remaining database then no one can know how many databases are there and etc).

If someone log-in with a particular database credentials he has to see only that particular database only. I tried to uncheck public option from login properties but unable to uncheck.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't actually a very good solution to this.

You can deny the [`VIEW ANY DATABASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189077%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) permission that is granted by default to the public role but then people without the permission only see databases that they actually own (in Management Studio).

Not all of those which they have permissions on.

Comment: Martin Smith if he takes away all the permission from a user and then grant them permission on a particular schema in a database will this not solve the issue ?

Comment: @MuhammedAli - No. That wouldn't affect the list of databases shown in Object Explorer at all. It shows all databases if you have `VIEW ANY DATABASE` permission even if you have zero permissions on the database itself.

Comment: Martin Smith Thnx for reply... plz send me or comment the query
which need to execute.. to restrict view any database to all logins

Comment: @San - `DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO Public` but you might find people see too few databases now dependant upon how your environment is set up. Even being in the `dbo_owner` role isn't enough to persuade SSMS to show it. If your databases are all connected to by their owner it will work for you though.